Luacov is not generating the xml output for Sonar
I am using luacov to generate the code-coverage.
I am able to see the coverage.out and using luacov-html I am able to get the index.html file as well.
But when I tried to post the report to Sonar, it is asking for the .xml file.
[Step 8/12] Error during parsing of the generic coverage report '/app/build/project/reports/index.html'. Look at SonarQube documentation to know the expected XML format.
